# How to add formula to Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

My question is how could I place this formula into a cell using PowerShell:

```
="('"&B6&"','"&TEXT(C6,"mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm")&"','"&D6&"','"&E6&"','"&F6&"','"&G6&"','"&H6&"','"&I6&"','"&J6&"','"&K6&"','"&L6&"','"&M6&"','"&N6&"','"&O6&"','"&P6&"'),"
```

I use it to generate a insert T-SQL statement from the content of my excel file. Whenever I place the formula into a cell using PowerShell I get an error. You may see reference image below.

[image: Here's the error message I get when executing my script]

This is how I've been doing it:

```
$Sheet.cells.item(6,43) = “=““('““&B6&”“','““&TEXT(C6,”“mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm”“)&”“','““&D6&”“','““&E6&”“','““&F6&”“','““&G6&”“','““&H6&”“','““&I6&”“','““&J6&”“','““&K6&”“','““&L6&”“','““&M6&”“','““&N6&”“','““&O6&”“','““&P6&”“'),”“”
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign formulas via the [`Formula`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) (or [`FormulaR1C1`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823188.aspx)) property:

```
$Sheet.Cells.Item(6, 43).Formula = "=`"('`"&B6&...&P6&`"'),`""
```

---

As a side note: you should avoid using typographic quotes. PowerShell sometimes treats them as straight quotes, but in general they tend to cause problems.

Comment: I added the formula property but I can't discard the quotes since I'm using them for text formatting.. I still need to find a way to deal with them.. thanks

Comment: Hmm... at least make the outer double quotes straight ones. Leaving nested double quotes as typographic quotes shouldn't be an issue then (you still need to escape them, though). ``"=`“('`“&B6&...&P6&`“'),`“"``

Comment: thanks @Ansgar I tried to apply escape and it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple trials using escape enabled me to land on my desired output:

```
 $Sheet.cells.item(6,43) = "=`"(`'`"&b6&`"`',`'`"&TEXT(c6,`"mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm`")&`"`',`'`"&d6&`"`',`'`"&f6&`"`',`'`"&g6&`"`',`'`"&h6&`"`',`'`"&i6&`"`',`'`"&j6&`"`',`'`"&k6&`"`',`'`"&l6&`"`',`'`"&m6&`"`',`'`"&n6&`"`',`'`"&o6&`"`',`'`"&p6&`"`'),`""
```